# How to crawl 1 million documents daily from web using apache Nutch 2.3

Tags: hadoop, web-scraping, web-crawler, hbase, nutch

I have configured apache nutch 2.3 with hadoop 1.2.1 and hbase 0.94.x. I have to crawl web for few weeks. About 1 million document are required to be crawled. I have four node hadoop cluster. Before this configuration, I setup nutch on single machine and crawled some documents. But is rate of crawling was not more than 50k to 80k. What should be the configuration of nutch so that it could crawl required amount of documents daily.

Comment: This is too broad of a question and lacks the detail necessary for us to give you a good answer.

Comment: This question is about how to configure nutch for above purpose only

Answer (score 1):

In general, you can set bigger TopN and also change `<name>http.content.limit</name>` in nutch-site.xml to -1.

Hope this helps,

Le Quoc Do

Comment: Can you refer to some tutorails for its details ?

Comment: For the details, you can read the description in the nutch-site.xml file. Sorry, I don't have a good tutorial for you.